# How do I run a code using Spark on VScode?

Tags: python, pyspark

I install pyspark using pip ( pip install pyspark )
I tried to run a very simple code using Spark on VScode:

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
Data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Study\\Spark\\Word_count.txt")
wordcount = Data.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" ")).map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b:a+b)
final = wordcount.count()
print(final)
```

I reinstall pyspark but it don't solve problem.
I tried another way to install Spark: Download spark from website / install it / set up env variables (SPARK_HOME / PYSPARK_HOME).... And ran it but it is still this problem

This is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kD8L.png)

Comment: You have to tell VSCode where your Python installation is, otherwise it wants to install its own.

Comment: It is very weird . I install findspark - Add 2 line 
import findspark
findspark.init()    
And the problem was solved .